# onChange event triggers before selecting the file

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom, dom-events

So i have a table that's generated with JavaScript from a JSON.
Inside the table there's a File Upload button that I need to swap images (all the images are in the same folder so I only need the name of the file)
The process of generation looks like this

```
    ImageClick = document.createElement('input');
    ImageClick.type = "file";
    ImageClick.id = "subida"
    ImageClick.onChange = handleFiles();
    cell.appendChild(ImageClick);
```

handleFiles function

```
    function handleFiles() {
        const fileList = this.files;
        console.log(fileList[])
}
```

[The result looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3628.png)

So when the table is generated, the handleFiles function is triggered right away, before even selecting a File, so I get an

```
Uncaught TypeError: fileList is undefined
```

as soon as the page loads.
If I try to load the file upload element with

```
filesElement = document.getElementById('subida')
```

and I try to console log the filesElement I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: filesElement is null.
```

I've been looking through the internet and I can't find an answer.
Also I can't use jQuery

Comment: No one has explained the _reason_ this happens. When looking at the `.onchange` attribute/property of an Image (or any) element, it requires a reference to the callback function. What you provided was the _result_ of calling the callback function -> `handleFiles()` - a reference to the callback function does not include the `()` - therefore, change that assignment to this: `ImageClick.onchange = handleFiles;` - You'll notice in the answer you accepted, that is the actual difference between your code and the answer code.

Comment: Note too, that `onChange` should be `onchange` in your code. (case matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work also:

```
    ImageClick.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
            const fileList = e.target.files;
            console.log(fileList);
        });
```

Comment: THis worked perfectly, I though on the addEventListener was "onChange" instead of change